# Difference between array and object in javascript? or Array Vs Object

Tags: javascript

How to recognize array & object in js where typeof doesn’t come in handy?

```
 var arr = [], ob = {};
```

As everything in js are objects,

```
if(typeof arr == typeof ob)  => returns true
```

I want a operator or ... that will tell me that the variable is an array. I can then use only the arrayfunctions to objects which are array. How is that possible?

Answer (score 41):

```
var arr = [], ob = {};
```

As everything in js are objects, even **Array is an Object but an instance of class Array

```
if(typeof arr == typeof ob)  => returns true as Both are **Objects
```

So, how will you to identify objects.

This is where instanceof operator comes in handy, to identify whether its an array you can put a additional check cde:

```
if(arr instanceof Object && arr instanceof Array) => returns true 
if(ob instanceof Object && ob instanceof Array) => returns false
```

Comment: @alex Oh i see. what will be the way out for it?

Comment: @AngelinNadar Use `Object.prototype.toString.call()` or new `isArray()`.

Answer (score 21):

You could use **Array.isArray()** method to check if a variable is array or otherwise.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(Array.isArray(myArray));
```

> true

Answer (score 6):

Among numerous simple/sophisticated comparisons, one difference is:

`var arr = []; # arr.length => 0`

`var obj = {}; # obj.length => undefined`

Comment: Upvoted because you took the trouble to flag comments for the sake of clarity. What is more, your answer is simple and straightforward.

Comment: This will work in the most cases. The only egde case is when you have object with `length` key. 

    `let obj = { length: 11 };  // obj.length => 11`

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways of differentiating between array and object, some on them are already mentioned above i would like to just add on above answers.

**First Approach**
Differentiation using length, length property exist on Array but doesn't exist on Object

```
 var arr = [1,2,3];  arr.length => 3

 var obj = {name: 'name'}; obj.length => undefined
```

Note: This approach fails when someone declares object like below, we can use this approach only when we are sure we will not get any object having length property

```
var rectangle = {length: 50, width: 50}; rectangle.length => 50
```

**Second Approach**
Using instanceof Array

```
var arr = [1,2,3]; arr instanceof Array => true
var obj = {name: 'name'}; ojb instanceof Array => false
```

**Third Approach** 
Using Array.isArray, this is most preferable approach and is supported by most of browser now

> Note:  Array.isArray is preferred over instanceof because it works
>   through iframes.

```
Array.isArray(arr) => true
true
Array.isArray(obj) => false
```

**If you want to support i.e 8 browser the use Object.prototype.toString**
We can write polyfill for i.e 8

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
Array.isArray = function(arg) {
return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
};
}

Object.prototype.toString.call(arr); =>"[object Array]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(obj); =>"[object Object]"
```

Reference: [isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Answer (score 0):

You can know only true objects this way:

```
if (typeof x === "object" && !(x instanceof Object && x instanceof Array)) console.log(x);
```

where `x` is the variable. This will produce only objects without arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but this answer doesn't really add any unique new information that wasn't already in the accepted answer.