# C# Get YouTube videoId from Json

Tags: c#, json, youtube, youtube-api

I need help. I'm making a program using the [youtube](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/dotnet) library, for c#.

For songs it works perfect. The problem is in the playlist I want to recover "videoId" to add it to a database, to put the videos in "queue".

I am using this method:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key= {API key} & maxResults = 50 & playlistId = {id}
```

which returns a json, but the problem is when I want to retrieve the "videoId" field.

I've tried a lot of things and can't get it to work. For example:

```
var json = wc.DownloadString ("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=API_KEY&playlistId=PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N");
dynamic data = JObject.Parse (json);
Console.WriteLine ("playlist" + data.items.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
Console.WriteLine ("playlist" + data.items.snippet.videoId);
Console.WriteLine ("playlist" + data.items.videoId);
Console.WriteLine ("playlist" + data.videoId);
```

The json that it returns is like this:

```
[
  {
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
    "etag": "_ON9HZaMSViWcbtKBRrSkH8D43Y",
    "id": "UEwtUFhLYjVqU2p3YlUwd3pBdUVvb0J2a1o5am5tWFI3Ti4xMjNBNTA2NDBDODU0QTE1",
    "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2021-05-17T09:33:13Z",
      "channelId": "UCn3uYZIYTMSvJraGKW2Blhw",
      "title": "C. Tangana, Niño de Elche, La Hungara - Tú Me Dejaste De Querer",
      "description": "C. Tangana – Tú me dejaste de querer ft La Húngara y Niño de Elche \n\nMERCHANDISING: https://www.ctangana.com \nIG: https://www.instagram.com/c.tangana/\nTW: https://twitter.com/c_tangana\nFB: https://www.facebook.com/ctanganaoficial/\n\n\nLyrics Tú Me Dejaste De Querer\n\nTú me dejaste de querer \nCuando te necesitaba\nCuando más falta hacía\nTú me diste la espalda\n\nTú me dejaste de querer\nCuando menos lo esperaba\nCuando más te quería \nSe te fueron las ganas \n\nYo me creía que era el más cabrón \nPero me estoy notando el corazón\nEstás apretando mucho mami déjalo\nSi quieres te doy la razón \nYo lo único que quiero es largarme de aquí \nMe da igual dónde, puedes elegir \nAlgún día dentro de poco me voy a arrepentir \nDe haberte confesado lo que me haces sufrir\n\nTú me dejaste de querer\nCuando menos lo esperaba\nCuando más te quería \nSe te fueron las ganas \n \nDe punta en blanco para ir a tu fiesta\nHe pasado tres días con la misma ropa puesta\nAndo loco por ti, perdiendo apuestas \nDime en quién piensas cuando te acuestas. \nPorque yo pienso en ti (son ilusiones)\nYo pienso en ti (son ilusiones)\nPorque yo pienso en ti (son ilusiones)\nYo pienso en ti (son ilusiones)\n\nTú me dejaste de querer \nCuando te necesitaba\nCuando más falta hacía\nTú me diste la espalda\n\nTú me dejaste de querer\nCuando menos lo esperaba\nCuando más te quería \nSe te fueron las ganas\n\n\n(C) 2020 Sony Music Entertainment España, S.L",
      "thumbnails": {
        "default": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ltmO9XQVdSg/default.jpg",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
        },
        "medium": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ltmO9XQVdSg/mqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 320,
          "height": 180
        },
        "high": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ltmO9XQVdSg/hqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 480,
          "height": 360
        },
        "standard": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ltmO9XQVdSg/sddefault.jpg",
          "width": 640,
          "height": 480
        },
        "maxres": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ltmO9XQVdSg/maxresdefault.jpg",
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 720
        }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Redlist - Las Mejores Canciones",
      "playlistId": "PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N",
      "position": 0,
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "ltmO9XQVdSg"
      },
      "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "CTanganaVEVO",
      "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCPTQlbt5SZO_SpYvC4Ygl-A"
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
    "etag": "4oVVxxoagCYATigtGVg53WXm2ak",
    "id": "UEwtUFhLYjVqU2p3YlUwd3pBdUVvb0J2a1o5am5tWFI3Ti5BRDA1REM4NDZFOEZFOEZF",
    "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2021-04-16T05:51:54Z",
      "channelId": "UCn3uYZIYTMSvJraGKW2Blhw",
      "title": "Omar Montes, Ana Mena, Maffio - Solo",
      "description": "“Familia, espero que os guste mi nuevo video “Solo” con mi hermanita Ana Mena y mi amigo Maffio y que todos lo bailéis y mandéis a todos y todas pa´ la Isla de las Tentaciones!!!! OS CAMELO”\n\nOMAR MONTES\nIG: https://www.instagram.com/omarmontesofficial/\nFB: https://www.facebook.com/omarmontessr/\nYOUTUBE: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-1BnbAPgInTpJiEi3z2d4A?sub_confirmation=1\n\n\nMusic video by Omar Montes, Ana Mena, Maffio performing Solo. (C) 2021 Sony Music Entertainment España, S.L.",
      "thumbnails": {
        "default": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/u12F1RY3WJQ/default.jpg",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
        },
        "medium": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/u12F1RY3WJQ/mqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 320,
          "height": 180
        },
        "high": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/u12F1RY3WJQ/hqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 480,
          "height": 360
        }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Redlist - Las Mejores Canciones",
      "playlistId": "PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N",
      "position": 1,
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "u12F1RY3WJQ"
      },
      "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "OmarMontesVEVO",
      "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCC9RzPoJumhh839VKwGBy6Q"
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
    "etag": "5zp32QT_yZ4pGN90Y7OKL2weCYU",
    "id": "UEwtUFhLYjVqU2p3YlUwd3pBdUVvb0J2a1o5am5tWFI3Ti42OTMwOTQzM0Q0ODU3QkFC",
    "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2021-06-04T19:39:36Z",
      "channelId": "UCn3uYZIYTMSvJraGKW2Blhw",
      "title": "BRYAN BAUTISTA - PARA MÍ (Official Video)",
      "description": "",
      "thumbnails": {
        "default": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cU_JGIuYsi0/default.jpg",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
        },
        "medium": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cU_JGIuYsi0/mqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 320,
          "height": 180
        },
        "high": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cU_JGIuYsi0/hqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 480,
          "height": 360
        },
        "standard": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cU_JGIuYsi0/sddefault.jpg",
          "width": 640,
          "height": 480
        },
        "maxres": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/cU_JGIuYsi0/maxresdefault.jpg",
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 720
        }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Redlist - Las Mejores Canciones",
      "playlistId": "PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N",
      "position": 2,
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "cU_JGIuYsi0"
      },
      "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "Bryan Bautista",
      "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCxCwpWTTehfcG0wmleUrReg"
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
    "etag": "t2UOHEo3irk0z4ollZOzB1H3eHE",
    "id": "UEwtUFhLYjVqU2p3YlUwd3pBdUVvb0J2a1o5am5tWFI3Ti41RUJCMkQ1ODk1RkI4NDg1",
    "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2021-05-14T19:46:26Z",
      "channelId": "UCn3uYZIYTMSvJraGKW2Blhw",
      "title": "Juhn, Jay Wheeler - Fragancia (Official Video)",
      "description": "Juhn, Jay Wheeler - Fragancia (Official Video)\nEncuéntrala en todas las plataformas: https://juhn.lnk.to/FraganciaYD\n\nSigue a Juhn\n➖ Facebook: https://smarturl.it/Juhn_fb\n➖ Instagram: https://smarturl.it/Juhn_ig\n➖ YouTube: https://smarturl.it/Juhn_yt\n➖ Spotify: https://smarturl.it/Juhn_sp\n\nLyrics/Letra\n\nNo sé que hago buscándote\nSi nadie me dice en donde estas\nTu recuerdo jugando con mi mente\nCuando te tengo, ahí mismo tú te vas\nPero ya yo lo entendí \nNo siempre en la vida uno tiene lo que quiere\nTal vez no eras para mi\nPero si supieras lo loco que me tienes\n\nNo hay quien te sustituya\nDesde que tu olor en mi cama me dejaste\nTan rico me lo hiciste\nQue por siempre en mi mente te quedaste\n\nNo hay quien te sustituya\nDesde que tu olor en mi cama me dejaste\nTan rico me lo hiciste\nQue por siempre en mi mente te quedaste\n\nBebecita, yo no olvido la fragancia de tu olor\nEl primer polvo fue rico\nY el segundo fue mejor\nY tú...\nComo media me viraste\nAbusadora, te subiste y no bajaste\nDe la machina, \nEmpieza otro siempre que termina\nQue le hablen sucio, dice que eso le fascina\nDe una mujer así, dime quien se olvida\n\nY no te niego que detrás tengo unas cuantas\nPero eres tú la que me dominas y me encantas\nLa que se lo lleva completo a la garganta\nSoy egoísta, no pidas que te comparta\nSi tú sabes que\n\nEse cuerpito tuyo es mío\nAunque yo no te hice mujer\nYo sé bien que te acuerdas de mi\nEn donde quiera que estés\n\nNo hay quien te sustituya\nDesde que tu olor en mi cama me dejaste\nTan rico me lo hiciste\nQue por siempre en mi mente te quedaste\n\nNo hay quien te sustituya\nDesde que tu olor en mi cama me dejaste\nTan rico me lo hiciste\nQue por siempre en mi mente te quedaste\n\nTe veo por Twitter\nY rápido me da con escribirte indirectas\nSi\nPuedo tener otros culos\nPero pa' mi tú siempre serás la correcta\nY, si me dejan como Pina, te comprometo\nY es que me enchulo ma' cada vez que te lo meto\nBaby yo soy tuyo completo\nPensándote no me puedo estar quieto\nNo, No, No...\n\nTe llamo pero no contestas\nDime si todavía estas dispuesta\nMi cama no es la misma si tú no te acuestas\nY sigo aquí...\n\nTe llamo pero no contestas\nDime si todavía estas dispuesta\nMi cama no es la misma si tú no te acuestas\n\nNo hay quien te sustituya\nDesde que tu olor en mi cama me dejaste\nTan rico me lo hiciste\nQue por siempre en mi mente te quedaste\n\nNo hay quien te sustituya\nDesde que tu olor en mi cama me dejaste\nTan rico me lo hiciste\nQue por siempre en mi mente te quedaste\n\nLa voz favorita baby\nEste ES Juhn \nJay Wheeler Jay Wheeler\nEl All Star\nJay Wheeler Jay Wheeler\nBaby\n\nHoy ando con Jay Wheeler\nLas estrellas siempre andan juntas\nUstedes lo saben ya\nMontana The Producer\nJonniel\nNosotros tenemos la coneccion directa con Willy Wonka\nLos dulces están de este lao\n\n#Juhn #JayWheeler #Fragancia",
      "thumbnails": {
        "default": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vN8un8VoPoQ/default.jpg",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
        },
        "medium": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vN8un8VoPoQ/mqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 320,
          "height": 180
        },
        "high": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vN8un8VoPoQ/hqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 480,
          "height": 360
        },
        "standard": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vN8un8VoPoQ/sddefault.jpg",
          "width": 640,
          "height": 480
        },
        "maxres": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vN8un8VoPoQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 720
        }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Redlist - Las Mejores Canciones",
      "playlistId": "PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N",
      "position": 3,
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "vN8un8VoPoQ"
      },
      "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "Juhn",
      "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCTeE0q8xCsbCBL4npUWDPFg"
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
    "etag": "9me0qaU5MYsZOaBTIqwnxgBpqP4",
    "id": "UEwtUFhLYjVqU2p3YlUwd3pBdUVvb0J2a1o5am5tWFI3Ti4xQTlCRURGNEY0QUEyODdD",
    "snippet": {
      "publishedAt": "2021-06-04T19:39:36Z",
      "channelId": "UCn3uYZIYTMSvJraGKW2Blhw",
      "title": "Nobeat, KHEA - Medio Crazy (Official Video)",
      "description": "Nobeat, KHEA - Medio Crazy (Official Video)\n\nEncuéntrala en todas las plataformas https://Nobeat.lnk.to/mediocrazyID\n\nSigue a Nobeat: \nInstagram: https://www.instagram.com/nobeat/ \nTwitter: https://twitter.com/nobeatmusic \nFacebook: https://www.facebook.com/nobeatmusic\nMailing List: https://Nobeat.lnk.to/MailingListID\n\n\nLyrics/Letra\nYa Nobeat\nSon of God\n \nSé que te pasa igual que yo\nte han roto el corazón\nAmigos pocos los que son\nNo sé  ni lo que somos pero sobra la pasión\nTú eres la que manda siempre te doy la razón\n \nTe dedico esta canción\nPa’ que veas que yo\nMe pongo romántico de vez en cuando\nMe encanta ver la cara que pones cuando dices\nTú solito no te mandas ay\n \nTú eres como medio crazy\nPero mejor que muchas por ahí\nQue delicia como bailas pam pam pam\nEl booty te hace así\n \nTú eres como medio crazy\nPero mejor que muchas por ahí\nQue delicia como bailas pam pam pam\n \nEs una loca pero ya no me manda snap\nAhora la tengo bailando como Addison Rae\nSe convirtió en mi favorito snack\nCuando está estresada soy su spa\nSiempre que le caigo\nSe la encesto como Michael\nElla es medio psycho y hace lo que quiere\nCon ese booty me distraigo\nSabe lo que tiene todo natural\nParece que te hicieron pa’ mi\nNo paramos de hablar desde que te conocí\nComo Ester Expósito tu eres elite\nTodos quieren tirarte pero son Mr. Bean\n \nY dale muévelo abusalo\nTú tienes poderes así que úsalos\nBaby excusas no\nPor favor\nTratando de entenderte me gradué\n \nPorque yeah\n \nTu eres medio crazy\nPero mejor que muchas por ahí\nQue delicia como baila pam pam pam\nEl booty te hace así\n \nTú eres como medio crazy\nPero mejor que muchas por ahí\nQue delicia como bailas pam pam pam\n \nElla no juega call of duty pero siempre me mata\nHeadshot\nQue rica que está no es intensa\nMedio crazy no es fácil entenderla\nEs como el algebra de Baldor hey\nNi si fueras un meme te comparto\nTú no eres segundo plato\nBaby please no me preguntes por mi ex no no\n \nNo invoques a Voldemort\nSi confías baby todo es más sencillo\nA mi no me preocupan los demás\nYo los piso y los apago como un cigarrillo\nY dale muévelo abúsalo\nTú tienes poderes así que úsalos\nBaby excusas no por favor\nTratando de entenderte me gradué porque\n \nTú eres como medio crazy\nPero mejor que muchas por ahí\nQue delicia como bailas pam pam pam\nEl booty te hace así\nTú eres com medio crazy\nPero mejor que muchas por ahí\nQue delicia como baila pam pam pam\nEl booty te hace así\n \nKHEA\nYoung Flex Argentina en la casa\nYeah\nNobeat\nDimelo KHEA\nNobeat\n2080’s\n\n#Nobeat #KHEA #MedioCrazy",
      "thumbnails": {
        "default": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eBwb5BA-stw/default.jpg",
          "width": 120,
          "height": 90
        },
        "medium": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eBwb5BA-stw/mqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 320,
          "height": 180
        },
        "high": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eBwb5BA-stw/hqdefault.jpg",
          "width": 480,
          "height": 360
        },
        "standard": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eBwb5BA-stw/sddefault.jpg",
          "width": 640,
          "height": 480
        },
        "maxres": {
          "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eBwb5BA-stw/maxresdefault.jpg",
          "width": 1280,
          "height": 720
        }
      },
      "channelTitle": "Redlist - Las Mejores Canciones",
      "playlistId": "PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N",
      "position": 4,
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "eBwb5BA-stw"
      },
      "videoOwnerChannelTitle": "Nobeat",
      "videoOwnerChannelId": "UCW56a1VqbINaFC50Es_EYvg"
    }
  }
]
```

I can't get it to return each video "videoId".

If anyone knows how to solve it, I will be very grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't use `dynamic`, make a C# class that represents the data being returned.  Then you can iterate through the items and for each one grab its `videoId`

Comment: https://quicktype.io/csharp can help you to create a class you can use to represent your JSON data. With the class you can do whatever you please.

Comment: why not use the google .net client library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON Path to get the video id.

Token to fetch all video id is `$...videoId`.

Check this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/nyngkK

You can use this portal to validate the JSON path token - https://jsonpath.com/

The below code demostrates the whole program which returns the output as

```
ltmO9XQVdSg
u12F1RY3WJQ
cU_JGIuYsi0
vN8un8VoPoQ
eBwb5BA-stw
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        RunTest().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
    
    public async static Task RunTest()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=<<Your Key>>&playlistId=PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N");
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(content);
            var videoIds = jObject.SelectTokens("$...videoId");
            foreach (var videoId in videoIds)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(videoId.Value<string>());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but It is not working, throw error. |ERROR|0| Unexpected command error: Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: @SantiagoMartinez - run this fiddle -https://rextester.com/KJW16966 and let me know if you see any error there. The code is expecting a string instead of JsonReader object.

Comment: user1672994 Yes, when copying the code as it is, it works correctly, but when I want to request the url, it throws the error that happens to you.` var json = wc.DownloadString ("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=API_KEY&playlistId=PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N");`

Comment: @SantiagoMartinez - the problem here that Google API returns the `JObject` instead of `JArray` which you have mentioned in your question. Converting `JArray` to `JObject` should fix your problem. Check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/nyngkK fiddle. Update your Key and you should able to see the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize your json file through a class and pull the data in a more practical way. See the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English only site. In the future please use links the English version of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend that you use the [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet) for which you can look at samples in the dotnet folder on the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples) or alternatively parse your Json into strongly typed classess.

The basic issue with your code is you are parsing as a `JObject` instead of a `JArray`. For details see: [Difference between array and object in javascript? or Array Vs Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803262/difference-between-array-and-object-in-javascript-or-array-vs-object)/

If you intend to continue using raw json. You can parse the Json as a `JArray` and select the videoIds from it.

```cs
public static List<string> ParseVideoIds()
{
    var json = TestConstants.JsonTest;
    JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
    var videoIds = jArray
        .SelectTokens("$...videoId")
        .Select(x=> x.ToString())
        .ToList();
        
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", videoIds));
    return videoIds.ToList();
}
```

Or you can make your code more formal and use strongly type classes to deserialize your json to.

1. You can copy json and within Visual Studio go to `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json as Classes` [image]
2. Once pasted you will have strongly type CSharp class which you can serialize and Deserialize using `NewtonSoft.Json` which I assume you are using from the `JObject.Parse` method in your question.
3. Instead of using `JObject.Parse`, identify the strongly typed classes in the `Rootobject` properties generated from pasting your json as classes. You can then deserialize the json as that type. In this case it is simply an array of `Class1[]`.
4. To do the actual serializations

```cs
var json = wc.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=API_KEY&playlistId=PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N");
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(json);
```

5. To extract just the videoIds from the strongly typed classes:

```cs
var videoIds = obj.Select(x => x.snippet.resourceId.videoId).ToList();
```

Putting it all together:

```cs
public static List<string> ParseVideoIds(string url)
{
    var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(json);
    var videoIds = obj.Select(x => x.snippet.resourceId.videoId).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", videoIds));
    return videoIds.ToList();
}
```

For reference, here are the class generated using Paste Json as Classes:

```cs
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Snippet snippet { get; set; }
}

public class Snippet
{
    public DateTime publishedAt { get; set; }
    public string channelId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Thumbnails thumbnails { get; set; }
    public string channelTitle { get; set; }
    public string playlistId { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
    public Resourceid resourceId { get; set; }
    public string videoOwnerChannelTitle { get; set; }
    public string videoOwnerChannelId { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnails
{
    public Default _default { get; set; }
    public Medium medium { get; set; }
    public High high { get; set; }
    public Standard standard { get; set; }
    public Maxres maxres { get; set; }
}

public class Default
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class High
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Maxres
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Resourceid
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string videoId { get; set; }
}
```

As noted, you can disregard `Rootobject`.

Additionally, feel free to refactor Class1 (or any of the other classes or Rootobject when using Json of a different schema) to something more intuitive. For example:

```cs
public class YouTubePlayListItem
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Snippet snippet { get; set; }
}
```

With that refactoring you would have:

```cs
public static List<string> ParseVideoIds(string url)
{
    var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YouTubePlayListItem[]>(json);
    var videoIds = obj.Select(x => x.snippet.resourceId.videoId).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", videoIds));
    return videoIds.ToList();
}
```

For Net 5.0, the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) outlines in more detail what is described above, as pointed out in the answer from [Gökdeniz Çetin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67846871/624988)

Comment: its cool but so long for get some simple data

Comment: I updated the answer with simpler code just to get the simple data, the video Id which the user asks. However, in practice you also need to get the data associated with some target data point, for example the Title, thumbnails, etc which the more verbose code provides.

Comment: Hello @AlexanderHiggins  First of all, I thank you for the extensive explanation and for taking the time to provide it.
second, copy the code, as it is but it keeps throwing error, and it does not recover the data.

In the first example: this is the error: ERROR | 0 | Unexpected command error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: second example: | ERROR | 0 | Unexpected command error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (eg {"name": "value"}) into type 'Main + Class1 []' because the type requires a JSON array (eg [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (eg [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (eg not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List <T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from

Comment: a JSON object. Path 'kind', line 2, position 9.

Comment: Please delete your last comment asap

Comment: In the second example, you must be getting different JSON. For example, YouTube is returning 1 playlist item instead of 2 or more in array as object. Again, this is why using the official sdk is recommended. As far as the unexpected command error, I have not seen that. I can only assume you are getting invalid JSON or null in response, for example your downloadstring is return a HTML with an error message because the video has been deleted or is no longer available. Again, look to the official YouTube SDK to handle issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going to every path you can use below code :

```
var json = wc.DownloadString ("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=API_KEY&playlistId=PL-PXKb5jSjwbU0wzAuEooBvkZ9jnmXR7N");
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);

foreach(var c in token.Children())
  {
     var m = c.SelectToken("$.." + "videoId");
     Console.WriteLine(m);                    
   }
```

Comment: It is not working, throw error. "|ERROR|0| Unexpected command error: Path returned multiple tokens."

Comment: I have used the same JSON shared by you. it is working without any error. Please share the code you using after this modification. Also, share the complete JSON .

Answer (score 0):

the returned json from youtube is a array so you must convert that with JArray

 its worked with your json

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

class program
{
    static string json = File.ReadAllText("json.json");
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic data = JArray.Parse(json);
        foreach (dynamic dynamic in data)
            Console.WriteLine(dynamic.snippet.resourceId.videoId);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

for understand what is returned json use [this website](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)