# java script function via 4 parameters

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and new in java script. I have a problem and have tried some ways but problem is here.
I wrote a function with 4 parameters and I want to get 4 arguments from input and save them to an array. It means every time gets 4 arguments and save them. this is my code but it is not working.

```
var personalInfo = {};

function addEmployee(firstName, lastName, hour, salary){
   personalInfo = personalInfo.push({'firstName':firstName, 'lastName':lastName, 'hour':hour, 'salary':salary});


return personalInfo;
}

addEmployee(personalInfo);
```

any solution would be my appreciate.

Comment: `personalInfo` is an object and an object does not have `.push` function. `push` is available on an array only.

Comment: You called your function with just _one_ argument, `addEmployee(personalInfo)` - so why should `lastName`, `hour`, and `salary` exist inside your function now?

Comment: Well. You're only passing one argument. `personalInfo` is an object, not an array. And the first time you call `addEmployee` you overwrite `personalInfo` with a number (or you would if it didn't throw an exception because it isn't an array to start with).

Comment: It would help you to understand the difference between an array and an object in JavaScript.  Your code just needs a minor change to work:  change var personalInfo = {}; to var personalInfo = [];  (square brackets).  Also see: [Difference between array and object in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803262/difference-between-array-and-object-in-javascript-or-array-vs-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change personalInfo to an array if you want to to push employees to an array. As also mentioned in the comments, you are only passing one parameter but you need to pass four parameters as shown in my example.

You also don't need to assign personalInfo when using push as this pushes a new object to the existing array.

```js
var personalInfo = [];

function addEmployee(firstName, lastName, hour, salary){
   personalInfo.push({'firstName':firstName, 'lastName':lastName, 'hour':hour, 'salary':salary});

return personalInfo;
}

addEmployee('first Name', 'last Name', '11', '100');
addEmployee('first Name 2', 'last Name 2', '10', '40');
console.log(personalInfo);
```

Comment: This is works!@Nathelol.. just another question: If I want push object with same first name and last name .how can I determine this user object has been added before?

Comment: @AliRezvani You can use .filter like this var dup = personalInfo.filter(p=> p.FirstName == firstName && p.LastName == lastName); and it dup has a value then its been added before.

Comment: @Nathelol.this is my  code but I get error:
var personalInfo = [];
function addEmployee(firstName, lastName, hourPerMonth, salaryPerHour) {
  // if (hourPerMonth > 160) return 'hourPerMonth is too much';
 
  for (let index = 0; index < personalInfo.length; index++) {
    if (personalInfo[index].firstName !== firstName && personalInfo[index].lastName !== lastName) {
      personalInfo.push({
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastName,
        'hourPerMonth': hourPerMonth,
        'salaryPerHour': salaryPerHour
      })
    
    }
  }

 return personalInfo;
}